# How can one bind data within the <head> of the document using Polymer?

Tags: data-binding, polymer, html-head

How can one bind data within the `<head>` tag of the document using Polymer?

I ask this because page information like `<title>` needs to change depending on what page the user is browsing and I'd like to remain consistent with the rest of the framework by writing `<title>{{title}}</title>`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect its not possible, because for data binding to work, the element (or the element with textContent) needs to have been inherited from Polymer, which of course `head` or `title` isn't.

What you could do is create an element (`<proxy-title>` ?) which is placed in the main body, and which programatically in an observer locates the title element in the dom and writes a property of title which it has.

Something like

```
<dom-module id="proxy-title">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display:none;
      };
    </style>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'proxy-title',
      properties: {
        title: {
          type: String,
          value: '',
          observer: '_titleChanged'
        }
      },
      _titleChanged: function(title) {
        document.title = this.title;
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

You would use it like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<!-- other head stuff -->
</head>
<body>
  <proxy-title title="[[someTitle]]"></proxy-title>

  <!-- ... other stuff here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks akc42. Will test this once home!